# exception.ReadTimeout not handling properly

Tags: python-requests, python-3.8

I looked through similar questions before posting and one helped with the continue statement. It is still not handling the ReadTimeout exception. I know it is user error somewhere. I am pinging a list of my subdomains and it fails after the active ones. After an inactive subdomain, I need it to proceed to the next one in the list.

```
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            r = requests.get("https://" + line, timeout = 2)
            try:
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    g.write(line + " is active!")
                    print(line + " is active!")
                    continue
            except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout, requests.exceptions.MaxRetryError, requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError, requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout, requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
                continue
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "is_alive.py", line 21, in <module>
    is_alive()
  File "is_alive.py", line 13, in is_alive
    r = requests.get("https://" + line, timeout = 2)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='111.111.111.111', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6eb79ad7c0>, 'Connection to 111.111.111.111 timed out. (connect timeout=2)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around wording my question in different ways, I found the simplest way to be this:

```
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                r = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '2', '-W 2', line])
                if r == 0:
                    g.write(line + ' is alive!\n')
                    print(line + ' is alive!')
                else:
                    continue
```